# How to prevent dartfmt to format single dot calls

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea

Before using dartfmt, this is how my code looks:

[image]

After formatting, it looks:

[image]

---

How can I prevent dartfmt from spoiling my code readability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a comment after `_ref`.

```
_subscription = _ref //
  .limit(_limit)
```